# Spring boot 2.4 Xmx On Layered Jar

Tags: spring-boot

How to configure Xmx and Xms with Spring Boot 2.4 onwards, as it has layer structure exploded in a docker image.
Conf file and jvm argument seems to be not straight option.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with setting the environment variable `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS`.

```
...
# Passing JVM arguments as an environment variable for layered jar to pick up.
ENV JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m -server" \

WORKDIR app
USER jboss
COPY --from=builder /home/jboss/app/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder /home/jboss/app/spring-boot-loader ./
COPY --from=builder /home/jboss/app/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder /home/jboss/app/application/ ./
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```